# SQL result not become as expect when using inner join

Tags: mysql, sql-server, join

I have an unanswerable sql query with 'inner join'. The result is not come as I expect. Even, I remove the 'inner join' - the result is also include everything - like the 'inner join' does.

What to do if I only wants the result comes from these conditions?

1. **prop_type='5'**
2. **not** prop_price='0'
3. prop_price2='0'
4. prop_price3='0'

Mysql:

```
select prop_lang, prop_type, prop_for, 
ppix_cover,prop_price,prop_price2,prop_price3 
from prop_db 
inner join prop_pix on prop_db.prop_sid=prop_pix.prop_sid 
where prop_db.prop_type='5' 
and prop_db.prop_lang='1' 
and prop_pix.ppix_cover='1' 
and prop_db.prop_for='1' or prop_db.prop_for='0' 
and prop_price3='0' 
and prop_price2='0' 
and not prop_price='0' 
group by prop_db.prop_sid 
order by prop_db.prop_id 
LIMIT 0, 9
```

This is the result from the query above.

[image]

As you see, the column 'prop_type' comes up with other value which I don't expected. And also the first row comes up with **price2** and **price3** that not ='0'.

What should I do to make the result show as the conditions above?

Comment: Your OR statement is the culprit. I don't have a sample of your tables, but the OR statement reads as (where this) OR (where this). So the query will include everything that matches both conditions. Use parenthesis to make the logic clear and prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A wild guess but it is usually spot on: `and` and `or` need parentheses.

Half-way down:

```
select prop_lang, prop_type, prop_for, 
ppix_cover,prop_price,prop_price2,prop_price3 
from prop_db 
inner join prop_pix on prop_db.prop_sid=prop_pix.prop_sid 
where prop_db.prop_type='5' 
and prop_db.prop_lang='1' 
and prop_pix.ppix_cover='1' 
and (prop_db.prop_for='1' or prop_db.prop_for='0') 
and prop_price3='0' 
and prop_price2='0' 
and not prop_price='0' 
group by prop_db.prop_sid 
order by prop_db.prop_id 
LIMIT 0, 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put your 'or' statement inside bracket

```
prop_db.prop_for='1' or prop_db.prop_for='0'
```

Try this, modified

```
   select prop_lang, prop_type, prop_for, 
   ppix_cover,prop_price,prop_price2,prop_price3 
    from prop_db 
    inner join prop_pix on prop_db.prop_sid=prop_pix.prop_sid 
    where prop_db.prop_type='5' 
    and prop_db.prop_lang='1' 
    and prop_pix.ppix_cover='1' 
    and (prop_db.prop_for='1' or prop_db.prop_for='0' )
    and prop_price3='0' 
    and prop_price2='0' 
    and not prop_price='0' 
    group by prop_db.prop_sid 
    order by prop_db.prop_id 
    LIMIT 0, 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this as well:

```
SELECT prop_lang, 
    prop_type, 
    prop_for, 
    ppix_cover,
    prop_price,
    prop_price2,
    prop_price3 
FROM prop_db 
INNER JOIN prop_pix ON prop_db.prop_sid = prop_pix.prop_sid 
WHERE prop_db.prop_type='5' 
    AND prop_db.prop_lang='1' 
    AND prop_pix.ppix_cover='1' 
    AND prop_db.prop_for IN ('1','0') 
    AND prop_price3='0' 
    AND prop_price2='0' 
    AND prop_price <> '0' 
GROUP BY prop_db.prop_sid 
ORDER BY prop_db.prop_id 
LIMIT 0, 9
```